# cURL easy option for X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN

Tags: c, ssl, curl, fedora

I'm having trouble connecting to a website that uses Let's Encrypt. The code is below, and it produces the error:

```
Error 60, SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK.
```

I've examined the CA certificate and end-entity certificate several times and everything looks OK to me.

I've seen similar problems with OpenSSL (prior to 1.0.2) and Wget (prior to 1.20.2). I want to see what happens with OpenSSL's `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN`. The problem is, I cannot find a cURL easy option for it.

How does one set `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` flag when using cURL's Easy API? (I think I am missing the name cURL uses for the option).

---

Here is the test program.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

const char ca[] = "./letsencrypt-ca.pem";
const char url[] = "https://openssl.org/news/secadv/20190910.txt";
const char of[PATH_MAX] = "./fetch.txt";

/* gcc -Wall test.c -o test.exe -lcurl -ldl */
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    CURL *curl = NULL;
    CURLcode res;

    fp = fopen(of, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open %s\n", of);
        goto finish;
    }

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize cURL\n");
        goto finish;
    }

    res = curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to set CURLOPT_URL\n");
        goto finish;
    }

    res = curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, ca);
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to set CURLOPT_CAINFO\n");
        goto finish;
    }

    res = curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to set CURLOPT_WRITEDATA\n");
        goto finish;
    }

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to download file, error %d, %s.\n",
            res, curl_easy_strerror(res));
        goto finish;
    }

    ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;

finish:

    if (fp)
        fclose(fp);

    if (curl)
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return ret;
}
```

---

Here's the Let's Encrypt X3 ca certificate. Running it through OpenSSL with `openssl x509 -in letsencrypt-ca.pem -text -noout` looks fine to me.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

---

Here are some cURL docs:

- [Easy interface overview](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html)
- [curl_easy_setopt - set options](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)

---

Here is the output using `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`:

```
$ ./test.exe
*   Trying 194.97.150.230:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to openssl.org (194.97.150.230) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ./letsencrypt-ca.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
Error 60, SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK.
```

---

Here are relevant version info

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 31 (Thirty One)
Release:        31
Codename:       ThirtyOne

$ /usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d FIPS  10 Sep 2019

$ /usr/bin/curl --version
curl 7.66.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.66.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1d-fips zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.2/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.39.2
Release-Date: 2019-09-11
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz Metalink NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

---

Here's an `lld` of `test.exe`:

```
$ ldd test.exe
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe6f5a2000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fa6857e6000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa6857df000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa685616000)
        libnghttp2.so.14 => /lib64/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007fa6855ed000)
        libidn2.so.0 => /lib64/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fa6855cb000)
        libssh.so.4 => /lib64/libssh.so.4 (0x00007fa68555b000)
        libpsl.so.5 => /lib64/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007fa685546000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fa6854b0000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fa6851d0000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fa68517e000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fa68508d000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fa685074000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fa68506b000)
        libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fa68501a000)
        liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fa685009000)
        libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib64/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007fa684ffa000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa684fe0000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa684fbe000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa685892000)
        libunistring.so.2 => /lib64/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fa684e38000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fa684e26000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fa684e1f000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fa684e06000)
        libsasl2.so.3 => /lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007fa684de6000)
        libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib64/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007fa684dc1000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fa684d94000)
        libcrypt.so.2 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.2 (0x00007fa684d59000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fa684ccb000)
```

Comment: Are you sure your build of curl/libcurl is using OpenSSL and not one of the half-dozen other TLS stacks curl supports (which don't all have the same options)? Can you try `openssl s_client` which implements nearly all (and only) OpenSSL options? In particular this one is `-partial_chain`. (Remember below 1.1.1 `s_client` doesn't send SNI by default, which most clients do and many servers require nowadays.)

Comment: @Dave - I believe the test program is using stock components from Fedora. I believe that would be cURL and OpenSSL. Or at least that is what `ldd` shows. I added a concrete example that [attempts] to fetch a file from `openssl.org`. Same problem with OpenSSL's site.

Comment: Okay it is OpenSSL. Since you're providing only the intermediate (not root) cert and can't specify partial-chain, yes libssl fails validation even on a good server. That's why I suggested `s_client` which _can_ specify `-partial_chain`. Alternatively, if the server is failing to provide the intermediate -- which you _could_ see just by looking at a connection attempt with `s_client` -- you can give libcurl a CAfile containing _both_ intermediate and DST Root, and even _without_ partial-chain libssl will use _both_ from the truststore and succeed.

Answer (score 0):

> How does one set X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN flag when using cURL's Easy API? (I think I am missing the name cURL uses for the option).

I think the short answer is, you can't because cURL is missing the option.

This looks like a cURL issue. `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` was suggested on the mailing list at [[PATCH] openssl: allow partial trust chains](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2015-11/0079.html).

It appears nothing came of it:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git
$ cd curl/
$ grep -IR X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN ./*
$
```

And specifically, the flag should show up somewhere around the context setup in [`lib/vtls/openssl.c:2727`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/vtls/openssl.c). This is where user specified options are used by libcurl:

```c
  if(ssl_cafile || ssl_capath) {
    /* tell SSL where to find CA certificates that are used to verify
       the servers certificate. */
    if(!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(BACKEND->ctx, ssl_cafile, ssl_capath)) {
      if(verifypeer) {
        /* Fail if we insist on successfully verifying the server. */
        failf(data, "error setting certificate verify locations:\n"
              "  CAfile: %s\n  CApath: %s",
              ssl_cafile ? ssl_cafile : "none",
              ssl_capath ? ssl_capath : "none");
        return CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE;
      }
```

Or maybe around [`2785`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/vtls/openssl.c):

```c
#if defined(X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST) && !defined(X509_V_FLAG_NO_ALT_CHAINS)
  if(verifypeer) {
    X509_STORE_set_flags(SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(BACKEND->ctx),
                         X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST);
  }
#endif
```

Somewhere in there `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` needs to be OR'd into the context flags when the user specifies his or her CA.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html accepint partial chains is the default since version 7.68.0 (January 8 2020). To disable, set CURLSSLOPT_NO_PARTIALCHAIN.

If you want to set the flag with an older version using the API:

- set CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION
- use the function to load the certificate and set the flag

An example for loading certificates can be found here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cacertinmem.html